# Deep Copy Pointer and Delete the Memory

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create Copy Constructor.

For example, There is a class like :

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class Test
{
    vector<string*> name;
public:
    ~Test();
    Test(const string& name);
    Test(const Test& t);
};

Test::Test(const Test& t)
{
    for (auto it = t.name.begin(); it != t.name.end(); it++) {
        this->name.push_back((*it));
    }
}

Test::Test(const string& name)
{
    this->name.emplace_back(name);
}

Test::~Test() {
    for (auto it = name.begin(); it != name.end(); it++) {
        delete (*it);
        (*it) = nullptr;
    }
}

int main() {
    Test t("Hello World!");
    Test t2(t);
}
```

When program is done, then error occured:
`Access violation reading location 0xDDDDDDDD`

I know that, it is because of t's name has deleted when t2 is called, however I don't know how to deep-copy of the name vector.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why not use `vector<string> name;`? Are you just trying to practice working with dynamic memory?

Comment: Please show the complete code.

Comment: .begin() and .end() is for vector. `Test t("Hello World!");` -> `t` is a string object which won't have begin and end

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes. I am just studying about cpp alone.. It is difficult language.

Comment: @Acorn That's the whole codes I wrote.

Comment: @djacob The code doesn't attempt to use begin and end on `t`. The error is a runtime crash.

Comment: @Eugene Definitely not. There is no constructor for `string`, there is no `#include`s, no `using namespace`, no `ticket` member...

Comment: @Acorn Updated. The problem was 'copy assignment operator'. However, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to make a deep copy, you need to copy what any pointer points to.
Like this:

```
name.push_back(new string(**it));
```

You also need to implement the copy assignment operator.

Comment: Can I get some advice about copy assignment operator?

Comment: @Eugene Use the [copy & swap idiom](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Copy-and-swap).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks!